# 1:Update from Sheet 1 static row to MasterSheet dynamic row 2:Show & Hide columns and rows base on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

SHEET 1

A: I want to update changes to my "MasterSheet" with the same mobile dynamic row by clicking the cell G1 or G6 macro buttons.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ISoV2q9g9L0cwP00eCfcb6k7FJ46C-E7GIOAjZCEZ3A/edit?usp=sharing

B: Hide columns and Show Columns D16

C: Hide rows and Show rows A21

Comment: Hi ! Could you make your [Spreadsheet public](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) so that we can take a look? I have made a request to access it. Thanks !

Comment: Hi Mateo, Hope you can access it now!. Thanks for your attention...

Comment: Hi ! So if you click either on ```G1``` or ```G6``` what do you exactly want to achieve on your ```Master Sheet```? Could you please clarify what the situations A,B and C mean? Are you suppossed to hide columns and rows and the ```Master Sheet``` to only show ```A21``` and ```D16```? If you could show your desired vs actual output it could really help understanding what you want to achieve. Thanks ! :D

Comment: Good Day Mateo,   1: When you click G1, it will copy "sheet 1" row 4 and dynamically paste it to the "Mastersheet" variable row for any updating.The row is variable because other data are being added regularly at the "Mastersheet".The same applies to G6.             2: Sheet1" D16.- if you select Section A&C, it will only show column A( E16:G16) and column C (K16:M16) and hide all other columns.                                        
3: "Sheet1" A21- if you select "Yes hide 5 rows" then row A22:A26 are hidden or "Yes hide 3 Rows" then row A27:A29 are hidden.Hope this will help.Thank you!!

Comment: Regarding the rest of the questions please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Each stack overflow question should be focused on a specific question and topic so instead of asking in the same post several questions please file a new question for each doubt you might have

Answer (score 1):

For the first of your doubts, you can simply use a combinaton of [getValues()](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to move your data from the source to the destination creating a new row in the destination. The following piece of code has self explanatory comments and will achieve what you are aiming for (same would apply for `G6`):

```js
function getDynamicRows(){
// Get source sheet 
 var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 1');
 // get values of the row we want to store
 var range = sheet1.getRange('B4:Q4').getValues();
 // Get destination sheet
 var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('MasterSheet');
 // Get range of destination sheet. If we want to append a new row at the end of 
 // our data we get the last row and add one as that is where the new data will go
 // and then set the number of columns the same as the ones from the original source
 // Finally just set values to the array of values we got from the source
 masterSheet.getRange(masterSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,range[0].length).setValues(range);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mateo. Please don't offer meta-advice in answers. A good way of thinking about answers is that although you are fixing one situation, advice given is for many future readers and not just the current one. The meta-advice is not wrong, just not relevant for those many readers. If you would like to offer it to the question author, please post it as a comment under the question.

Comment: Thanks! It's fine to add question guidance under your answer, but if you post it under the question, the question author will get a notification in their inbox.